# Mappings for three different visual modes

Tags: vimrc

Is it possible so that each of the different visual modes have different mappings? For example:

```
visual-block-noremap     A      BB
visual-line-noremap      A      CC
visual-normal-noremap    A      DD
```

If so, what are the various mappings that can be used? Normally, I've used `vnoremap` for everything.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has no built-in way to differ mappings for Visual sub-modes, and I can't think of any good use case for this either, but it's certainly not too hard to do. For instance,

```
xnoremap <expr>A VisualMapping('BB', 'CC', 'DD')

function! VisualMapping(char, line, block) abort
    if mode() ==# 'v'
        return a:char
    elseif mode() ==# 'V'
        return a:line
    elseif mode() ==# "\<C-V>"
        return a:block
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: `visualmode()` returns the last visual mode; you want the current mode (i.e. `mode()`).

Comment: @user938271 Ah, yeah... I didn't check it at all. When you do it with `<expr>` you need mode(), but when it's without it you need visualmode() (as you've just left it).